# angular js i18n translate loading issue

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am using  [http://github.com/angular-translate/angular-translate](http://angular-translate.github.io/) for website localization.

when page load it's working perfectly.
But load page partially, the translation works in lagging way. That means,

Partial page loads first with the tag and showing in the same way in the page.

```
{{ 'CONGRATS' | translate }}
```

After 5 or 8 seconds, it translate to original text. Sometime network may be slow. In that time this should not be show like that.

Translation should be done properly, before page show to the user.

How to rectify this error ?
What mistake I made here ?

I've loaded the angular js scripts in the following manner.

```
<script src="scripts/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/angular-route.min.js"></script>
<script src="App/angular-translate.js"></script>
<script src="App/angular-translate-loader-static-files.js"></script>
<script src="App/angular-translate-loader-partial.js"></script>
<script src="App/app.js"></script>
```

I am loading the languages in app.js like following,

```
var langSvSE = {
    "ENTER_EMAIL_ADDRESS": "Ange e-post adress",
    "PASSWORD": "Lösenord",
    }
 $translateProvider.translations('sv-SE', langSvSE);
$translateProvider.preferredLanguage('sv-SE');
```

Comment: put your controller function inside $viewContentLoaded.

Comment: Show how you are loading translation (key,value) file?

Comment: @SubashSelvaraj, edited in the last line .. can you please look into that ?

Comment: @Ved, can you provide sample code please ? I don't understand ..

Comment: I mean the content which you want to render on page, keep that inside $viewContentLoaded. check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27129829/angularjs-viewcontentloaded-fired-before-partial-view-appears

Comment: why don't you use translate as an attribute like, <div translate="CONGRATS"></div>

Comment: @SubashSelvaraj, I think both are same only the syntax is different, correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: @Ved, By frank, Seriously I don't understand. I am totally new to this angular js. Can you provide any fiddler or any sample ?

Comment: If you use it as attribute you wont see the text, which is your problem.