# Binding issue using ES6 + Angular1.5 + ui-router

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, ecmascript-6

This is hanging the browser. I believe I'm not returning data the right way and misunderstanding some concepts, perhaps a timing problem?

### controller.js

```
export default class XController {
    constructor($stateParams, YService) {

        this.getSlugByName = function(name) {
            return YService.get({name: name}).then(getSuccessFn, getFailFn);

            function getSuccessFn(data) {
                return data[0].slug;
            }

            function getFailFn() {
                console.error('Something went wrong');
            }
        }
    }
}
XController.$inject = ['$stateParams', 'YService'];
```

### template.html

```
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="each in vm.mainObject.objects"> // each is a name
    <a ui-sref="resolver({slug: vm.getSlugByName(each) })" class="btn">{{ each }}</a>
</ul>
```

### routes.js

```
static resolver($stateParams, XService) {
    return XService.get({ slug: $stateParams.slug });
}
```

### component.js

```
import templateUrl from './template.html';
import controller from './controller';

let xComponent = {
  restrict: 'E',
  bindings: {
    'mainObject': '<'
  },
  templateUrl: templateUrl,
  controller,
  controllerAs: 'vm'
};

export default xComponent;
```

---

### Update

Added component file that explain where `objects` bind is coming from

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a timing problem. I moved out `YService` and placed it as a resolver, that way the data will be available later on the controller. This is possible because I'm using angular-ui-router, otherwise I'd try with `$scope.$on('$viewContentLoaded')` as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27129829)

Answer (score 0):

I think one issue is that your method is inside the constructor:

```
export default class XController {
  constructor($stateParams, YService) {
  }

  function getSlugByName(name) {
    return YService.get({name: name}).then(getSuccessFn, getFailFn);

    function getSuccessFn(data) {
      return data[0].slug;
    }

    function getFailFn() {
      console.error('Something went wrong');
    }
  }
}

XController.$inject = ['$stateParams', 'YService'];
```

Where is your vm.objects coming from?

Anyway, try that, see if it fixes your issue.

Comment: objects are coming for a binding on component level. That's why is not in the controller. Let me try that but I have a good feeling

Comment: Ok.  I tested it and `function` is an unexpected token. I removed it but I'm still getting the same problem