# Accessing rendered DOM element

Tags: angularjs, cordova

I'm trying to access a DOM element after it gets rendered by AngularJS.

In my template I've this div:

```
<ion-view view-title="MAP" name="tab-map">
    <ion-content has-tabs="true" style="text-align:center;">
        <div style="width:100%;height:400px;" ng-attr-id="{{'canvas_map_'+place.id}}" class="map"></div>
    </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

So, in template's controller I'm trying to get its new id:

```
var mapId = document.querySelector('.map').id;

console.log("Map id: "+mapId);
```

But unfortunatelly I'm receiving pre-render code: {{'canvas_map_'+place.id}} and I want to get the rendered id name that is "canvas_map_2"... Somebody can help me?

Comment: You can use timeout for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use  `$timeout` and `$viewContentLoaded` to achieve what you asked

```
   $scope.$on('$viewContentLoaded', (event) => {
              $timeout(()=> {//When $timeout used , the code inside it is executed in next $digest cycle
                var mapId = document.querySelector('.map').id;
                console.log("Map id: "+mapId);
          },0);
    }
```

Comment: Thank you, but is it the better way to do it or is just a workaround?

Comment: You can use it. I use same and never has any issue. Let me if you find something better

Comment: Perfect! I'll do it!

Comment: I was reading this topic and the anwer's author recommended use .directives to realize DOM manipulation...   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27129829/angularjs-viewcontentloaded-fired-before-partial-view-appears

Comment: Yes. My answer scope is limited . You DOM manipulation , than it must be inside directive.